# How can I block certain URLs in apache httpd when using proxy pass?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, node.js

My site is using apache httpd to do the reverse proxy to an app running in Express (Node.js app). Have 2 express servers, one for backend, another for frontend hosting.
Right now I'm trying to block malicious requests that is coming to my site so it returns a 404 or bad request.

My some-site-ssl.conf sample is below, but it doesnt look like its blocking the malicious websites, any help would be awesome!!  Thank you.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

      SSLEngine on

      SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/some-site.com/fullchain.pem
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/some-site.com/privkey.pem
      Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?.*(-|.)?bad-word(-|.).*$  [NC]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://(www\.)?.*(-|.)?bad-word(-|.).*$  [NC]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

      ProxyRequests On

      ProxyPass /api http://some-site.com:3000/api
      ProxyPassReverse /api http://some-site.com:3000/api

      ProxyPass / http://some-site.com:4226/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://some-site.com:4226/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The first thing you should do to secure your server is to turn `ProxyRequests Off` when you're using a reverse proxy. Read [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control access to any resource using the `Location` tag, and with it, you can disable access from certain hosts to your resources, like this:

```
<Location "/denied/resource">
    <RequireAll>
        Require not ip 1.2.3.4
        Require not host spammer.domain
        Require all granted
    <RequireAll>
</Location>
```

The access rights are inherited from top to bottom, so denying access to `/` will practically lock out that client from your site (unless, of course, access is granted to a lower level resource, so it is possible not to have access to `/`, but being able to access `/this/one/`). See [the Apache HTTP server documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) for more info.

And like @Freddy said, you really should remove that `ProxyRequests On` line.

Comment: Thanks Lacek.  One follow up question if I might, what if I have multiple URL's, would it be possible to read this <Location "blahblahblah></Location> from a file, or do I have to specify all of them in the same conf file? I might have hundreds of URLs I wanted to block for instance. Thank you again.

Comment: It is possible to include a config file to another, using the `Include` directive. However, giving hundreds of URLs as a `Location` might not be the best idea (I really don't know if it could affect performance, but I suspect it might). You should consider putting the would-be-protected URLs under a common root, and protect that resource only, or using a firewall to deny access from problematic IPs altogether.